# Does C++ Catch has something like NUnit's TestCase with multiple parameter/input options

Tags: c++, unit-testing, catch-unit-test

NUnit has the following feature where you can specify different values for a test with a TestCase attribute. Does Catch has something similar?

```
[TestCase(12,3,4)]
[TestCase(12,2,6)]
[TestCase(12,4,3)]
public void DivideTest(int n, int d, int q)
{
  Assert.AreEqual( q, n / d );
}
```

I need to run the same unit test with different data values but each be different unit tests. I can copy/paste TEST_CASE/SECTION and change values but is there a clean way to do it like NUnit does.

I'm finding it really hard to even figure out what to search for. Catch uses TEST_CASE for a unit test which is completely different than what NUnit calls TestCase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not quite find the equivalent of what you are looking for, but you are not required to copy and paste everything at all:

```
#include "catch.hpp"

// A test function which we are going to call in the test cases
void testDivision(int n, int d, int q)
{
  // we intend to run this multiple times and count the errors independently
  // so we use CHECK rather than REQUIRE
  CHECK( q == n / d );
}

TEST_CASE( "Divisions with sections", "[divide]" ) {
  // This is more cumbersome but it will work better
  // if we need to use REQUIRE in our test function
  SECTION("by three") {
    testDivision(12, 3, 4);
  }
  SECTION("by four") {
    testDivision(12, 4, 3);
  }
  SECTION("by two") {
    testDivision(12, 2, 7); // wrong!
  }
  SECTION("by six") {
    testDivision(12, 6, 2);
  }
}

TEST_CASE( "Division without Sections", "[divide]" ) {
  testDivision(12, 3, 4);
  testDivision(12, 4, 3);
  testDivision(12, 2, 7); // oops...
  testDivision(12, 6, 2); // this would not execute because
                          // of previous failing REQUIRE had we used that
}

TEST_CASE ("Division with loop", "[divide]")
{
  struct {
    int n;
    int d;
    int q;
  } test_cases[] = {{12,3,4}, {12,4,3}, {12,2,7},
                    {12,6,2}};
  for(auto &test_case : test_cases) {
    testDivision(test_case.n, test_case.d, test_case.q);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Looks like there isn't anything there. I don't think it would be hard to have something like

    TEST_VARIABLES(int n, int d, int q)
    TEST_VALUES(n=12, d=3, q=4)
    TEST_VALUES(n=12, d=2, q=6)
    TEST_CASE ...

in the framework. I still think there is a little bit of copy and paste but that's what I'll go with for now.